# Plot the distribution of values in a column based on category in another column

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two columns of data as indicated below:

```
data = {'labels': {0: '00',
  1: '08',
  2: '00',
  3: '08',
  4: '5',
  5: '04',
  6: '08',
  7: '04',
  8: '08',
  9: '5',
  10: '5',
  11: '04',
  12: '5',
  13: '00',
  14: '08',
  15: '5',
  16: '00',
  17: '00',
  18: '04',
  19: '04'},
 'scores': {0: 0.0023585677121699122,
  1: 0.056371229170055104,
  2: 0.005376756883710199,
  3: 0.05694460526172507,
  4: 0.1049131006122696,
  5: 0.008102266910447686,
  6: 0.09154342979296892,
  7: -0.03761723194472211,
  8: 0.010718527281161072,
  9: 0.11988838522095685,
  10: 0.09070139731152083,
  11: 0.02994813107318378,
  12: 0.09277903598030868,
  13: 0.062223925985664286,
  14: 0.1377963110579728,
  15: 0.11898618005936024,
  16: -0.021227109409528988,
  17: 0.008938944493717238,
  18: 0.03413068403999525,
  19: 0.058688416622356965}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want am trying to plot the values in the `scores` and color it according to the `labels`. I have tried

`sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='labels',y='scores');`

This works but it doesn't show the clusters(each x value is separated) as shown here [image]

I want the points to be in the same space and colored differently according to the `df['labels']`.

Comment: like this: `sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='labels',y='scores',hue='labels')`?

Comment: `sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='labels',y='scores',hue=df['labels'].tolist());` works in colorising the points. My source of confusion is from the x-axis. How do I choose it such that the data isn't plotted as distinct categories? I want everything to be in the same space instead of it being on vertical lines as indicated in the plot.

Comment: so, you don't want data to be distributed along the `x` axis? if so, you can do something like this `sns.scatterplot(data=df,x=0,y='scores',hue='labels')`

Answer (score 1):

`sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='labels',y='scores', hue='labels')`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.